Surprising results comparing 2 pd.array
Using python 3.10.13, pandas 2.2.0 with numpy 1.26.4, I expected to be able to use something like (as required by the ruff linter) :
# this is False
$ (pd.array([""]) == pd.array([""]))[0] is True
False

# this does work
$ (pd.array([""]) == pd.array([""]))[0] == True
True

# though
$ (pd.array([""]) == pd.array([""]))[0]
True

Note : wrapping pd.array([""]) in a list solves the problem, I am asking why here it seems True != True.
Additional information :
# you end up with a StringArray when using
$ pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[""])).unique()

# this behavior is also true for
$ (pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[""])) == pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[""]))).values[0][0] is True
False

# one needs to use pd.DataFrame.equals for it to work
$ pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[""])).equals(pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[""]))) is True
True


From the docs for is:

The operators is and is not test for an object’s identity: x is y is true if and only if x and y are the same object. An Object’s identity is determined using the id() function.

So, the id values will not be the same. And that makes sense, because despite appearance pd.array([""]) == pd.array([""]))[0] is not a bool, but an np.bool_, i.e., it's a different object.
np_bool_ = (pd.array([""]) == pd.array([""]))[0]

id(np_bool_)
# 140727655433136

type(np_bool_)
# numpy.bool_

id(True)
# 140727548180584

type(True)
# bool

So, by extension, your pd.DataFrame examples make similar sense. A bool passed to pd.DataFrame will become an np.bool_, while df.equals properly returns a bool.
type(pd.DataFrame([bool(1)]).iloc[0,0])
# numpy.bool_

